# html5sql.process inside for loop

Tags: database, html, sqlite, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing an iPad application using jQuery mobile 1.1.1 and PhoneGap. 
I use `html5sql.js` to do my database operations and it works fine.

How can I use `html5sql.process()` inside of a for loop?

Ex:

```
html5sql.process( {
                    "sql": "select id,count from my_table",
                     "data": [],
                      "success": function(transaction, results){        
                    },  
                     function(transaction, results){

                        for(var i = 0; i < results.rows.length;i++){

                             /// Line 5
                 html5sql.process( {
                                      "sql": "select count(*) from my_table1 where id= ?",
                                    "data": [results.rows.item(i).id],
                                     "success": function(transaction, resultsD){        
                                 },  
                                      function(transaction, resultsD){

                                            if(results.rows.item(i).count == resultsD.rows.length){
                                  //do my task

                            }
                                       },function(){}
                                    );
                                 }
                           },function(){}
                       );
```

I don't get any output from this code. When I check it, it works only up until line 5. The code after that isn't working. What could be causing a problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that the whole structure of your code is wrong. You shouldn't request the database inside the loop but outside. Here's a chunk from my code that generates a jQM listview. The query result is placed into an array and the javascript is parsing the actual HTML code out from it. Hope it helps

```
function showRecords() {
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = '<li data-role="list-divider">Header</li>';
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM OrderList", [], function(tx, result) {
         for (var i = 0, item = null; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
            item = result.rows.item(i);
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML += 
             '<li data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">'
            +'<a href="#"><p style="font-weight:bold;">'+item['catNo']+'</p>'
            +'.......................
            +'</li>';  
          }     
          $('#results').listview('refresh',true);
      });
   });
}
```